# How to add a null production in NLTK grammar?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

I came up with a CFG for a text input having left recursion and I would like to eliminate it using the well known rule of adding another production including a null production. Can someone please guide me as to how to add a null production in NLTK grammar string?

I tried with NT -> '', but it did not work.

Comment: Not sure in a grammar sense, but for Python `None` is the equivalent of `null` in other languages. Perhaps that might help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is something not very intuitive, but in NLTK CFG empty space serves as a null/lambda terminal.

```
S -> S 'a' 'a' 
S -> S 'a' 'a' T
T -> 'b' S
S ->
```

or equivalently:

```
S -> S 'a' 'a' | S 'a' 'a' T |
T -> 'b' S
```